# spring boot security asking for unexpected authorization

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I am making an authentication project using spring boot.
I have used spring starter security but the problem I am facing is I want to permit some pages to be accessible by all. But spring is asking for authentication in using those web pages also.

I have tried this code:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","/signUp").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
       }
```

*i have used following code as well but that also not working in the expected way as i described and asking for authentication*

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
     }
```

it is expected to allow access to these pages without authentication but it is asking for authentication.

Comment: What URL do you call? Show also your full Spring Security configuration. Did you annotate your class in the right way?

Comment: `
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
 
 @Autowired
 private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
 
 @Bean
 public AuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
 DaoAuthenticationProvider provider=new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
 provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
 provider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
 return provider;
}
 
 [above method here which i have posted]
}
`

Comment: can you share the request you are making

Answer (score 0):

Try  `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.Method,"/endpoint")` and `/**` with `configure(HttpSecurity http)`

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

         http
         .csrf().disable()
         .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/**","/signUp").permitAll()
         .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/endpointPOST").permitAll()
         .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/endpointGET").permitAll()
         .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }
```

If you want to bypass the *Security Filter Chain* for some endpoints then use `configure(WebSecurity web)`.

```
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
          .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/signUp", "**/endpoint/**");
    }
```

***[HttpSecurity vs WebSecurity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56389047/10961238)***