# Spring boot: How to skip basic-auth for particular endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I tried many ways but When I hit /healthCheck URL it prompts to enter username and password.
I have below code in EmailsecurityAdapter.java class

```
import com.cellpointmobile.email.services.AuthenticationService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class EmailSecurityAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }


@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/healthCheck**");
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "**/heathCheck/*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .access("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')")
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
}

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        //https://www.browserling.com/tools/bcrypt
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

what should I change in configure() method to publicaly access healthCheck url?

Postman response GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/heathCheck

```
<Map>
    <timestamp>2019-09-13</timestamp>
    <status>401</status>
    <error>Unauthorized</error>
    <message>Unauthorized</message>
    <path>/heathCheck</path>
</Map>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "**/heathCheck/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .access("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')")
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
}
```

OR use `web.ignoring()` in *configure(WebSecurity web)* which will ingore all security filters for endpoints specififed with it. After that you can remove it from `configure(HttpSecurity http)` and keep `configure(WebSecurity web)` above `configure(HttpSecurity http)`.

**[HttpSecurity vs WebSecurity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56388865/spring-security-configuration-httpsecurity-vs-websecurity/56389047#56389047)**

```
 @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
          .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.yourMethod, "**/heathCheck/**");
    }
```

---

UPDATE:

```
@Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web
              .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.yourMethod, "**/heathCheck/**");
        }

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "**/heathCheck/*").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .access("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')");
}
```

Comment: It's not working, I am getting popup to enter username password when I access http://127.0.0.1:8080/healthCheck

Comment: Hi @PraveenD, have you tried with `configure(WebSecurity web)`

Comment: @PraveenD can you update with your current configuration and are you geeting spring security default login page or what kind of popup

Comment: @PraveenD From updated code I can see `WebSecurity` has been kept below `HttpSecurity`. keep  WebSecurity first and then HttpSecuriy as in updated answer

Comment: Hi @PraveenD, I have noticed that you have `healthcheck` and making a request at `heathCheck` two diff endpoints

Comment: I moved above even getting same error. I didn't understand: making a request at heathCheck two diff endpoints

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199442/discussion-between-patel-romil-and-praveen-d).