# Spring security antMatcher not working as expected

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have my custom controller `"/my-endpoint"` and spring app with the following configuration:

```
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/my-endpoint", "/health")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(DENY_RESOURCE_PATTERNS)
                .denyAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()

    }
```

It seems that for a unanimous user it working fine. But if I already authorized (using oauth2) and my session(or token) is expired -> spring trying to redirect me to the login page.

I don't want this, I want to allow any user to connect to "/my-endpoint" endpoint.

What I forgot to configure?

The interesting thing, that built-in endpoint `"/health"` working as expected, even if session is expired.

Comment: What's the `my-endpoint` ?

Comment: @chaoluo, its my custom controller, it just return static json object

Comment: add the exact URL you are calling to.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe, localhost:3030/my-endpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `configure(WebSecurity web)`. It will bypass the Spring Security Filters and will allow any user to access the endpoint. see **[HttpSecurity vs WebSecurity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56388865/spring-security-configuration-httpsecurity-vs-websecurity/56389047#56389047)**

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
          .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.yourMethod, "/health")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.yourMethod, "/my-endpoint");
    }
```