# How to allow Swagger to bypass WebSecurityConfig?

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, swagger

I have a basic config like this

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

 protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        // We don't need CSRF for this example
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                // dont authenticate this particular request
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll().
                // all other requests need to be authenticated
                        anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                        // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
                        // store user's state.
                        exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

So basically it allows /authenticate through but everything else needs token. How do I allow it to bypass Swagger as well? It's make development difficult because the team relies on Swagger to see the API docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the swagger endpoints in *antMatchers* with `permitAll().` OR you can use *configure(WebSecurity WebSecurity)* and use `.ignoring()` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56389047/10961238)

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/**", "/swagger*/**", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```