# Spring Boot HttpSecurity always 403 forbidden

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I always get http status 403. I have this security configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
        .cors().and().csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/users/login/").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
}


@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

I cannot post to **/api/users/login**

> 2019-10-15 12:25:49.567[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7423[0;39m
>   [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m
>   [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m
>   "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={} [2m2019-10-15
>   12:25:49.576[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7423[0;39m [2m---[0;39m
>   [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m
>   [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m
>   Mapped to public
>   org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity>
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
>   [2m2019-10-15 12:25:49.605[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7423[0;39m
>   [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m
>   [36mo.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor [0;39m [2m:[0;39m
>   Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json,
>   application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
>   [2m2019-10-15 12:25:49.608[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7423[0;39m
>   [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m
>   [36mo.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor [0;39m [2m:[0;39m
>   Writing [{timestamp=Tue Oct 15 12:25:49 CEST 2019, status=403,
>   error=Forbidden, message=Access Denied, path=/ (truncated)...]
>   [2m2019-10-15 12:25:49.661[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m7423[0;39m
>   [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m
>   [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m
>   Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 403

Comment: Maybe try removing the `.authorizeRequests()` call. Regardless, a 403 error isn’t a CORS issue and isn’t caused by your CORS configuration.

Comment: In your post, I have not seen any code regarding authentication.

Comment: .antMatchers("/api/users/login/").permitAll() ?

Comment: @ErayTuncer Try `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/users/login").permitAll()`, also note that you have `.antMatchers("/api/users/login/")` and you are makin an request to `/api/users/login` note extra `/` in your antMatchers

Comment: @PatelRomil please write this comment as an answer. You are totaly right!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/users/login").permitAll()`, also note that you have `.antMatchers("/api/users/login/")` and you are makin an request to `/api/users/login` note *extra /* in your antMatchers.

You can also use `configure(WebSecurity web)` which will bypass the Spring Security filter chain as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56388865/spring-security-configuration-httpsecurity-vs-websecurity/56389047#56389047)