# Spring security: HttpSecurity vs WebSecurity

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Can someone explain what are the differences between **HttpSecurity** & **WebSecurity** and which one should I be using based on scenarios? I am currently using HttpSecurity and it is working fine for me but I am wondering if I am loosing any functionality by not adding WebSecurity. FYI, I am using spring boot.

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56388865/spring-security-configuration-httpsecurity-vs-websecurity

Comment: I just read it now. Thanks for the link! It answers my questions.

Comment: Yes, it does answer my question.