# How to whitelist single endpoint in Spring Boot application?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-security

I am new to Spring Boot and trying to find out the way to whitelist an
end-point. I have enabled the Spring Security.

I have a controller class with endpoint Hello, which should return "hello"
in response and want anyone to be able to access this endpoint without authentication required.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = {"/employee"})

public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository empRepose;

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService empService;

    @Autowired
    private Utility utility;

    @PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
    @GetMapping(value = "/hello", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String home() {
        return "Hello Employee!";
    }
}
```

Spring Security configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationBasicAuth extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    RegisterUser beanRegisteruser;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
       /* httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();*/

              /*httpSecurity
                        .httpBasic()
                        .and()
                        .authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/employee/**").permitAll()
                        .and()
                        .csrf().disable();*/

        httpSecurity.csrf().disable();

        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();

    }
```

I tried so many ways to whitelist all endpoints or even 1 endpoint for which I don't need to go for authentication.

Please, help me to find out what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Your code should work. You have to add the response code, error message and/or the log messages to your question. Did you enter the URL of your application into a browser or do you use any other client?

Comment: Hi Nikolai, I tried on both Browser and client, browser redirecting me to login page and client giving me 401 error.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve using `configure(WebSecurity web)` and/or `configure(HttpSecurity http)` If you are using both of them note that you have to keep `configure(WebSecurity web)` above `configure(HttpSecurity http)`. You may see more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56388865/spring-security-configuration-httpsecurity-vs-websecurity/56389047#56389047)

---

**`configure(WebSecurity web)`**

General use of WebSecurity `ignoring()` method *omits* Spring Security and none of Spring Security’s features will be available.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/hello")
}
```

---

**`configure(HttpSecurity http)`**

You can also use `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method with `.permitAll()` as below

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/hello").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Comment: hi Romil, I tried but didn't work... Do we need to mention ApplicationBasicAuth Class somewhere else also or need to put some configuration in the application.properties file related to it?

Comment: @lalitbhadula Have you tried both approaches?. Please share your updated code with a project structure.

Comment: @lalitbhadula, Remove `@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")` from `/hello` and try again