# Spring security - 403 status response on OPTIONS call

Tags: spring, spring-security, cors

I have backend hosted on Heroku, and frontend on Netlify. When I call endpoint on backend it sends preflight OPTIONS but it gives 403 status.
I did search for solution but it still not working.

I want to be able to call `"/authenticate"` endpoint with `"POST"` method with body from FE to BE.

Spring security configuration (just configuration methods)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    ...

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception
    {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/authenticate", "/register")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/token")
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**")
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
                "/configuration/ui",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/configuration/security",
                "/swagger-ui.html",
                "/webjars/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {

        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/authenticate").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/user-data").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(new JwtFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();

        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of(<MY-URL>));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setMaxAge(Long.valueOf(3600));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }
}
```

And call from FE

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('POST', API_URL + '/authenticate', true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    req.withCredentials = true;
    req.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
        if (req.readyState === 4) {
            if(req.status === 200) {
                console.log(req.responseText);
                isAuthenticationSucessful = true;
            }
            else
                console.log("Error loading site");
        }
    };

    req.send(JSON.stringify({username, password}));
```

Browser dev-tools:

```
Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing
Reason: CORS request did not succeed
```

Comment: config security as `http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()).and()...`

Comment: @HMD Thank you! Also in `setAllowedOrigins()` I put `myurl.com/` , but browser send request with `Origin: myurl.com` without that trailing slash, and it also was place where fix was necessary

Comment: @HMD I was too fast. This don't fixed all my problems. It was sending successful request but responses wasn't accepted by browser. But I made it works, and you can check my answer if you want. And thanks again, your comment helped me go in right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Make sure that in `setAllowedOrigins("https://myrul.com")` you don't have trailing slash or you have exactly the same origin that your browser send.

If your endpoint is in `web.ignoring(...` delete it from here and put it in (with my example endpoint) `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()`

(`web` and `http` according to my code in question)

**Longer**

So how I said in my comment, one thing that make it not working correctly was setting `setAllowedOrigins("https://myrul.com/")` in `corsConfigurationSource`.
Notice that trailing slash.

But I noticed in dev-tools that browser send origin header like this: `Origin: https://myrul.com` without trailing slash. To make it works I have to change allowed origins to proper origin like this: `setAllowedOrigins("https://myrul.com")` (without trailing slash).
This make browser able to send requests to server, and get 200 response, but browser don't accept response from server cuz CORS.

The next thing was that I have my endpoint in `web.ignoring("/authenticate")...` and according to this question
[Spring Security Configuration - HttpSecurity vs WebSecurity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56388865/spring-security-configuration-httpsecurity-vs-websecurity)
this statement prevents Spring Security Filter Chain where it should header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` which tell browser that it can accept response. [MDN Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

So the answer for that was take my endpoint from `web.ignoring("/authenticate")` to `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()`.

But this makes another problem, that is it will go now to filter chain and to my custom filter `http.addFilterBefore(new JwtFilter()...`, so make sure to adopt custom filters to yours need.