# How to disable Spring Boot Authentication control for a particular Rest Controller

Tags: spring-boot, security, authentication, okta, http-status-code-401

I made a CRUD app using Angular on client side and Spring Boot on the backend. I implemented then authentication with Okta and everything works fine.
The problem is that I want to retrieve some data from database for my homepage, and show those info even if no user is authenticated, but I keep receiving a 401 Unauthorized http response.

I read some other question here in stackoverflow and these are all the configuration that I tried in my Spring server:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
```

1)

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().oauth2Client().and().oauth2Login()
            .and().csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/stats/**");
    http.cors();
}
```

2)

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/stats/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().oauth2Client().and().oauth2Login();
    http.cors();
}
```

They don't work. This is the @RestController that I'm trying to contact for my GET methods:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/stats")
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
public class StatsController {

@Autowired
private CompanyManagerService companyManagerService;
@Autowired
private ReservationService reservationService;
@Autowired
private ReviewService reviewService;
@Autowired
private UserService userService;


@GetMapping("/company")
public ResponseEntity getCompanyCount(){

    return new ResponseEntity(companyManagerService.getCompanyCount(), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@GetMapping("/field")
public ResponseEntity getFieldCount(){

    return new ResponseEntity(companyManagerService.getFieldCount(), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@GetMapping("/reservation")
public ResponseEntity getReservationCount(){

    return new ResponseEntity(reservationService.getCount(), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@GetMapping("/review")
public ResponseEntity getReviewCount(){

    return new ResponseEntity(reviewService.getCount(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

How can I solve this situation?

Comment: So, there is one API that you don't want to authenticate?

Comment: Yes. All the methods in StatsController provide info and statistics that I show on my homepage, and must be shown before user login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure your security configuration class *SecurityConfig*  is annotated with `@EnableWebSecurity` and `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)`
- The security configuration class is in follows the package structure and scanned by Spring. [spring-component-scanning](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning)
- The application does not have a context path if you are using a context path then you may use `**/stats/**` or `/context-path/stats/**`

You may use *configure(WebSecurity web)* that will bypass the security filter chain and you will be able to access the *GET APIs*

```
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("**/stats/**");
    }
```

If you are using both `configure(WebSecurity web)` and `configure(HttpSecurity http)` methods, make sure you have placed *configure(WebSecurity web)* above the *configure(HttpSecurity http)* as described [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56389047/10961238)

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

     // Other Configurations...

     @Override
     public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
         web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("**/stats/**");
     }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .csrf().disable().cors().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("**/stats/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Client()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login();
      }

     // Other Configurations...

}
```

Comment: I added annotations, the new configure method that receives a WebSecurity instance and added .csrf().disable() into the http method chain. I can't neither add cors().disable nor remove http.cors() at the end of the configure(http) method, otherwise I get XmlHttpRequest Error ( No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header). Anyway, it still doesn't work

Comment: Seems I solved. I kept http.cors() at the end, I removed .cors().disable() in the HttpSecurity method chain and I changed path from ** /stats/ ** to /stats/**. Now it works

Comment: @FabrizioGabriele, Great!

Answer (score 0):

Update the configure method to this and try

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/stats/**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Client()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login();
  }
```

Comment: What's the difference with the code I already have? I see it's the same, just written vertically.