# Spring Security (with Spring Boot) returns login form as a response for POST, EDIT, DELETE operation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, authorization

I am making a meme sharing app where I have secured some REST endpoints like POST, DELETE and EDIT. And removed authentication for GET operations.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/xmeme/delete/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/xmeme/edit/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/xmeme/post").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "USER")
        .antMatchers("/user/register").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin().permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl("/xmeme/memes", true)
        .and()
        .logout().permitAll()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
}


 @Override public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
     web.ignoring().antMatchers("/xmeme"); 
     web.ignoring().antMatchers("/xmeme/memes"); 
     web.ignoring().antMatchers("/xmeme/meme/**"); 
 }
```

Now the issue is when I am trying to POST a meme and use the Authorization > Type > Basic Auth option in POSTMAN, I am getting the login form as response. And same happens with the EDIT and DELETE operations.

I couldn't find a solution. Can someone please suggest some workaround for this issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsFW3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNP1m.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have enabled Form Login for you application in `configure(HttpSecurity http)`

```
http.formLogin()
```

If you want to enable HTTP Basic authentication, you need to configure it in `configure(HttpSecurity http)`

```
http.httpBasic()
```

If you have configured both `formLogin` and `httpBasic`, Spring Security will use content-negotiation to determine how it should behave towards an unauthenticated user based on the content type being requested.

Answer (score 0):

1. you should specify the authority with the *ROLE_* prefix such as *ROLE_ADMIN* and *ROLE_USER* in `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method.
2. `configure(WebSecurity web)` method should be placed before the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` [check detailed usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56389047/10961238)
3. Disable the CSRF token using `http.csrf().disable()`
4. Verify that user *om* has the correct authority assigned

---

```
 @Override public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
     web.ignoring().antMatchers("/xmeme"); 
     web.ignoring().antMatchers("/xmeme/memes"); 
     web.ignoring().antMatchers("/xmeme/meme/**"); 
 }

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/xmeme/delete/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/xmeme/edit/**").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/xmeme/post").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER")
        .antMatchers("/user/register").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin().permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl("/xmeme/memes", true)
        .and()
        .logout().permitAll()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Romil and Eleftheria Stein-Kousathana, your suggestion worked!